# Pandas appending moving averages of frame to frame

Tags: python, pandas

I can take a SMA of a column and then append it to the dataframe without a problem

BUT then I tried to take a SMA of the column values that met a certain criteria (a subset of all the rows, in my case a sma of goals scored *df.f* in the last *averaging_period* homegames *df[df.ha=='H']*)

and I get

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

My code is wrong, I am taking the moving average of the homegames like I want, but it is removing the row when it gets to an away game, not skipping them in the averaging:

```
sma = df[df.ha=='H'].f.rolling(window=averaging_period).mean()

df['f_sma%s' % averaging_period] = sma.array
```

Here are the lengths of the things I am trying to append together

```
len(df)
   Out[3]: 12938
len(sma.array)
   Out[4]: 6458
len(df[df.ha=='H'])
   Out[5]: 6458
```

Anyone know how I can get the sma function to not average the goals of the away game, but still retain a row that is the value of the sma up to that point? Therebye returning an array the same length as my dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **.loc** filtering when assigning the rolling values to the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

t = pd.DataFrame({'G':['a','a','h','a','h','a','a','h'],'scores':[3,2,1,5,3,1,6,5]})

t['avg'] = np.nan

t.loc[t.G=='h','avg'] = t[t.G=='h'].scores.rolling(window=2).mean()
```

Output:

```
   G  scores  avg
0  a       3  NaN
1  a       2  NaN
2  h       1  NaN
3  a       5  NaN
4  h       3  2.0
5  a       1  NaN
6  a       6  NaN
7  h       5  4.0
```

Comment: I don't think that will work. If I have AAHA  and I do 0040 (say 4 goals were scored in the home game) the 4 game rolling average will be 1. I am going to try and retain the indices and then 'tack them on' to corresponding indices in my df

Comment: Changed the answer to a proper one.

Comment: Thanks, I figured I would have to use .loc but didn't have time to work on this, you have figured it out for me